# Moq verify fails when SelectMany

Tags: c#, linq, unit-testing, moq, structuremap

I am using NUnit, Moq and StructureMap.

I have a following NUnit test:

```
    [Test]
    public void ShouldCallCustomMethod_ForAllICustomInterfaceMocks()
    {
        var customInterfaceMock1 = new Mock<ICustomInterface>();
        var customInterfaceMock2 = new Mock<ICustomInterface>();

        ObjectFactory.Inject(customInterfaceMock1.Object);
        ObjectFactory.Inject(customInterfaceMock2.Object);

        var sut = new SUT();
        sut.MethodThatShouldCallCustomMethodOnMocks();

        customInterfaceMock1.Verify(m => m.CustomMethod());
        customInterfaceMock2.Verify(m => m.CustomMethod());
    }
```

ICustomInterface:

```
public interface ICustomInterface
{
    IEnumerable<Type> CustomMethod();
}
```

Now if implementation of SUT class looks like this:

```
public class SUT
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> MethodThatShouldCallCustomMethodOnMocks()
    {
        var result = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<ICustomInterface>()
             .SelectMany(i => i.CustomMethod());


        return result;
    }
}
```

test from above fails due to method CustomMethod not being called on mocks.
However, if I change implementation of SUT class to this:

```
public class SUT
{
    public IEnumerable<Type> MethodThatShouldCallCustomMethodOnMocks()
    {
        var customInterfaceInstances = ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<ICustomInterface>();

        foreach (var instance in customInterfaceInstances)
              instance.CustomMethod();


        return ...
    }
}
```

test passes!
The difference is that instead of iterating with SelectMany i use foreach, but test results differ (in second case CustomMethods do get called on mocks).

Can somebody explain that behaviour?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this might be a case of deferred execution. `SelectMany` doesn't execute immediately. The `IEnumerable` that's returned must be enumerated for your methods to be called. Try adding `ToList()` after the `SelectMany()` method to force the `IEnumerable` returned from `SelectMany` to be evaluated.

Comment: Spot on! That was exactly the case. So to clarify: my methods will be called as soon as I use SUT's method return value - that's when IEnumerable will be evaluated.

Comment: @JarekMazur Yes, you're right. And so the call to `ToList()` can move into your unit test.